# Table has multiple enteries for the same record I need to get one column value where the other column value is maximum for the same record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table GPS that has 3 columns number time location

table has multiple entries for the same record as devices keep sending there latest locations to db.

I need to get all the distinct values from number column where time column has the latest value.

Is there a simple way to do this?

All your help is much Appreciated.

```
----------------------------------
NUMBER          TIME            LOCATION
----------------------------------
600004  2013-11-21 15:30:41.000 716.845531877897
600004  2013-11-22 15:21:28.000 716.845531877897
600004  2013-11-23 15:36:58.000 716.843840384205
600004  2013-11-24 15:08:53.000 716.848112801147
600004  2013-11-25 15:22:42.000 716.770758576572
600004  2013-11-26 15:16:21.000 716.771869331508
600004  2013-11-27 15:23:07.000 716.850630248914
600004  2013-11-28 15:16:50.000 716.851575132123
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output data

Comment: number int,
time datetime,
location varhcar(15),
location is basically the lat long values for used for location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS rn,
```

wrap it in a subquery and filter:

`rn = 1`

to get the latest per `number` record.

Comment: Hi Giorgos Betsos, I have updated my question can you please make a query for this one? I am new to SQL. your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @user3655503 The data you posted do not add anything new to the question. Try: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS rn) AS t WHERE t.rn = 1`.

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful. I Modified this a little bit and got results. Great help.